# Transfer call from SIP trunk to Twiml application

Tags: twilio, sip, twilio-twiml

I have a phone number registered in Twilio that I wanted to use for both a Twiml application and an Elastic SIP Trunk (connected to Asterisk). The idea is that inbound calls hit the Twiml app first and then can be forwarded to the Asterisk server if needed, while outbound calls just go via the SIP trunk. (The reason it needs to be a SIP trunk instead of simply using SIP Registration with Programmable Voice is because that is the only way to have E911 support for outbound calls.)

Twilio support told me that it is not possible to use the same number for both.

Because of that limitation, my current plan is to use two Twilio phone numbers. My published phone number will go to the Twiml application, and a second number that I will not give out will go to the SIP Trunk. (Twilio allows number spoofing of other numbers on your account, so I will have the Asterisk server pretend to use my primary number for outbound calls instead of using the second private number.)

In order for this to work, I need to be able to transfer calls from my Twiml app to Asterisk and from Asterisk server back to the Twiml application. The former is easy: just use `<Dial>` with a SIP URL that points to the trunk. The latter is what I need help with. (I also want to do this in case someone does manage to call the second number - I want them to be redirected to the Twiml app.)

As far as I can tell, the only way for me to transfer calls back into my Twiml application is to forward the call from the Asterisk server back to my public number. The problem is that I think this will look like an outgoing+incoming call and I will get double-billed for these minutes. I'm already paying for another number, and I really don't want to have to pay extra for the minutes too.

Is there a better (or "official") way to transfer a call back to the Twiml app? Or am I wrong about Twilio seeing (and billing) this as two calls?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you cannot use the Twilio number for both a Twiml application and an Elastic SIP Trunk (connected to Asterisk). Did they indicate why?

Just don't assign that particular number to your Elastic SIP Trunk and you should be able to assign it to your TwiML application for inbound calls and use a  when you want to forward the the call to your Asterisk PBX.

For outbound calls, you can have you Asterisk PBX send calls with that number as CallerID to your Elastic SIP Trunk Termination URI.

For E911 calls from the Twilio Elastic SIP Trunk, you should have a number associated with your Elastic SIP Trunk, enabled for Emergency Calling, so when 911 calls are placed, the CallerID of that number is used for outbound calls and calls can be returned to that number should the connection get disconnected.

If you did go the second route you mentioned, can you have your Asterisk Server send the call to a Twilio Programmable Voice SIP Domain, maybe have a Dial Plan defined so an Asterisk prefix digit sends calls out this different trunk. Not sure this will work (since mixing Elastic SIP Trunking with Programmable Voice in this manner) but one idea. Your Asterisk server will remain in the call path.

Comment: A number that has Emergency Calling enabled cannot be associated with a Twiml application. The steps to enable emergency calling require you to set the number to point to the SIP Trunk, and enabling Emergency Calling locks those settings so they can't be changed. The site says "you must disable Emergency Calling on this number in order to change its destination."

Comment: So to answer your first sentence, no, they did not indicate why, but I tried to do it anyway and it just can't be done.